# How do I disable all auto-formatting in vscode in OSX?

Tags: css, macos, format, visual-studio-code, autoformat

I've been trying to **disable auto-formatting on save** for vs code and have had no luck. I have just started using it and use no extensions.

I've tried adding the setting:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

To no avail.

It continues to take my perfectly formatted css and strip all the whitespace and stick it on one line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I just want it to save the file as I have written it.

Comment: VSCode does not do that by default, you might have an extension installed [like this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify) that does it for you. Try to disable all extensions, restart and save ... you will see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like your css is being minified when you save the file. As a formatter would not place all the css on one line.

Are you using a build process? eg: gulp, grunt, sass, less, etc..

Comment: No. Just creating and editing a file and then saving. Thanks. I'll try searching keeping that in mind though. Maybe I've enabled some sort of build without intending to.

Comment: It looks like I was using SASS so that was causing the minification. Thank you so much for the help Brian.